# WCF service without adding reference in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I created a WCF consuming application in WPF by adding service reference.Now its working fine.But now i have a new requirement that is, i want to call the service dynamically by entering the URL,username and password.

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](http://www.pinfaq.com/1494/wcf-service-proxy-on-the-fly-dynamically-using-wsdl-url) website?

Comment: Let me check,and will post the status

Comment: hi @JeroenHeier :i have some douts
Copies all that codes and added wanted references.After that i created and event for button to execute the function.
` private void getData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceDetail sd = new ServiceDetail();
            GenericService gs=new GenericService();
            sd.WSDLUri =new Uri(WSDLUri.Text);
            sd.ServiceUri = new Uri(ServiceUri.Text);
            sd.ContractName = ContractName.Text;
            sd.MethodName = MethodName.Text;
        }
`what is that payload list and WSDLuri mean,serviceuri?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a WCF client without adding a service reference with the use of ClientBase, but you will still need a reference to the interface for the compiler to knowwhat functions to call.

It works like this:

```
    public class ServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IService>, IService {       
      public ServiceClient() {
      }

  public ServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }


      public void Login(string user, string password) {
            return base.Channel.Login(user, password);
      }
    }

    NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
    binding.TransactionFlow = true;

    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(youraddress);

    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(binding, address);

    client.Login("xxx", "yyy");
```

Comment: Thanks,
You are saying there is no way to call without knowing the interface.right?

Comment: If you event dont want that then you can go for the link that Jeroen posted in the comment

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.pinfaq.com/1494/wcf-service-proxy-on-the-fly-dynamically-using-wsdl-url) website for a general idea. Create a new VisualStudio Solution and add a WCF Service Application project and an Unit Test Project. Put the following code in the test project (a slightly modified version of the code in the link) and add the missing references to the unit test project. Start the WCF service without debugging, change the portnumber in the test if needed and run the test. As mentioned in the article, the code can still use some adjustments before it could be put into production.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    public class ServiceDetail
    {
        public Uri WSDLUri { get; set; }
        public Uri ServiceUri { get; set; }
        public String ContractName { get; set; }
        public string MethodName { get; set; }
    }

    public class GenericService
    {
        public object Call(ServiceDetail svc, List<object> payLoads)
        {
            //Import WSDL
            WsdlImporter imptr = ImportWSDL(svc.WSDLUri);
            //Extract Service and Data Contract Descriptions
            Collection<ContractDescription> svcCtrDesc = imptr.ImportAllContracts();
            //Compile the description to assembly
            var assembly = GetAssembly(svcCtrDesc);
            if (assembly == null) return null;
            //Extract all end points available on the WSDL
            IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint>> allEP = GetEndPointsOfEachServiceContract(imptr, svcCtrDesc);
            IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint> currentSvcEP;
            if (allEP.TryGetValue(svc.ContractName, out currentSvcEP))
            {
                //Find the endpoint of the service to which the proxy needs to contact
                var svcEP = currentSvcEP.First(x => x.ListenUri.AbsoluteUri == svc.ServiceUri.AbsoluteUri);
                //Generate proxy
                var proxy = GetProxy(svc.ContractName, svcEP, assembly);
                //Deserialize each payload argument to object
                List<object> pls = new List<object>();
                foreach (var pl in payLoads)
                {
                    object clrObj = null;
                    try
                    {
                        clrObj = Deserialize(pl.ToString(), assembly);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        clrObj = pl;
                    }
                    pls.Add(clrObj);
                }
                //Find opration contract on the proxy and invoke
                return proxy.GetType().GetMethod(svc.MethodName).Invoke(proxy, pls.ToArray());
            }
            return null;
        }

        private Assembly GetAssembly(Collection<ContractDescription> svcCtrDesc)
        {
            CodeCompileUnit ccu = GetServiceAndDataContractCompileUnitFromWSDL(svcCtrDesc);
            CompilerResults rslt = GenerateContractsAssemblyInMemory(new CodeCompileUnit[] { ccu });
            if (!rslt.Errors.HasErrors)
                return rslt.CompiledAssembly;
            return null;
        }
        private object GetProxy(string ctrName, ServiceEndpoint svcEP, Assembly assembly)
        {
            Type prxyT = assembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.IsClass && t.GetInterface(ctrName) != null && t.GetInterface(typeof(ICommunicationObject).Name) != null);
            object proxy = assembly.CreateInstance(prxyT.Name, false, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance,
                                    null, new object[] { svcEP.Binding, svcEP.Address }, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);
            return proxy;
        }
        private WsdlImporter ImportWSDL(Uri wsdlLoc)
        {
            MetadataExchangeClient mexC = new MetadataExchangeClient(wsdlLoc, MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet);
            mexC.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
            MetadataSet metaSet = mexC.GetMetadata();
            return new WsdlImporter(metaSet);
        }
        private Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint>> GetEndPointsOfEachServiceContract(WsdlImporter imptr, Collection<ContractDescription> svcCtrDescs)
        {
            ServiceEndpointCollection allEP = imptr.ImportAllEndpoints();
            var ctrEP = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint>>();
            foreach (ContractDescription svcCtrDesc in svcCtrDescs)
            {
                List<ServiceEndpoint> eps = allEP.Where(x => x.Contract.Name == svcCtrDesc.Name).ToList();
                ctrEP.Add(svcCtrDesc.Name, eps);
            }
            return ctrEP;
        }
        private CodeCompileUnit GetServiceAndDataContractCompileUnitFromWSDL(Collection<ContractDescription> svcCtrDescs)
        {
            ServiceContractGenerator svcCtrGen = new ServiceContractGenerator();
            foreach (ContractDescription ctrDesc in svcCtrDescs)
            {
                svcCtrGen.GenerateServiceContractType(ctrDesc);
            }
            return svcCtrGen.TargetCompileUnit;
        }
        private object Deserialize(string xml, Assembly assembly)
        {
            Type ctr = GetDataContractType(xml, assembly);
            return Deserialize(xml, ctr);
        }
        private object Deserialize(string xml, Type toType)
        {
            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Position = 0;
                DataContractSerializer d = new DataContractSerializer(toType);
                return d.ReadObject(stream);
            }
        }
        private Type GetDataContractType(string xml, Assembly assembly)
        {
            var serializedXML = ConvertToXML(xml);
            var match = assembly.GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == serializedXML.Root.Name.LocalName);
            return match;
        }
        private XDocument ConvertToXML(string xml)
        {
            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Position = 0;
                return XDocument.Load(stream);
            }
        }
        private CompilerResults GenerateContractsAssemblyInMemory(params CodeCompileUnit[] codeCompileUnits)
        {
            // Generate a code file for the contracts 
            CodeGeneratorOptions opts = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
            opts.BracingStyle = "C";
            CodeDomProvider pro = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
            // Compile the code file to an in-memory assembly
            // Don't forget to add all WCF-related assemblies as references
            CompilerParameters prms = new CompilerParameters(new string[] { "System.dll", "System.ServiceModel.dll",
                "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"});
            prms.GenerateInMemory = true;
            prms.GenerateExecutable = false;
            return pro.CompileAssemblyFromDom(prms, codeCompileUnits);
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Arrange         
            var target = new GenericService();
            var serviceDetail = new ServiceDetail
            {
                WSDLUri = new Uri("http://localhost:13152/Service1.svc?singleWsdl"),
                ServiceUri = new Uri("http://localhost:13152/Service1.svc"),
                ContractName = "IService1",
                MethodName = "GetData"
            };
            var arguments = new List<object> { 5 };

            // Act
            var result = target.Call(serviceDetail, arguments);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual("You entered: 5", result);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: an error occuring on
**var svcEP = currentSvcEP.First(x => x.ListenUri.AbsoluteUri == svc.ServiceUri.AbsoluteUri);**
.The error is {"Sequence contains no matching element"}

Comment: Code re-checked and executed. Check your serviceDetail.ServiceUri port settings. Look in the debugger in currentSvcEP; there must be one entry.